# PgAdmin 3 crashed when font size was increased

Tags: pgadmin-3

I am using PgAdmin 3 on Postgresql 9.4 on Windows 7. All things work well until I resized  browser fonts from 12 to 18. I cant create database, rename table and even change the font size to what it was before. Many things stopped working. I have tried to uninstall Postgres and install another version but still the behavior is same, no change. Please what do I do. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by deleting PgAdmin3 file in the Windows registry.

1. Save a copy of the Registry editor, so that in-case there is any error, you can 
   restore the saved copy.
2. Double click on the "Registry editor" at `C:\windows\regedit`.
3. Click on `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software`.
    delete the folder `PgAdmin 111`.

Re-start Pgadmin. Then increase font size to 12 - 14 Time and it works fine.